# MVVM Light Binding SeekBar's Progress

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I'm attempting to change the text in a TextView by adjusting a SeekBar. If I set the TapSelectionProgress property directly (`TapSelectionProgress = 2;`), the TextView updates. However, the binding update never triggers from the UI.

In Main.axml:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/tapSeekBar"
    android:max="5"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:padding="50dp" />
```

In MainViewModel.cs:

```
public int TapSelectionProgress
{
    get
    {
        return _tapSelectionProgress;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _tapSelectionProgress, value);
        if (value == 0)
        {
            TapSelectionText = "Tap Selection: Off";
        }
        else
        {
            TapSelectionText = String.Format("Tap Selection: {0}", value);
        }                
    }
}

public string TapSelectionText
{
    get
    {
        return _tapSelectionText;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _tapSelectionText, value);
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.cs:

```
_bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(
            () => TapSeekBar.Progress,
            () => Vm.TapSelectionProgress));
```

I've tried updating the source trigger:

```
_bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(
            () => TapSeekBar.Progress,
            () => Vm.TapSelectionProgress).UpdateSourceTrigger("ProgressChanged"));
```

[But this gives me an InvalidCastException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1wYo.png)

I've also tried setting BindingMode to TwoWay. I've not been able to find any examples of MVVM Light with a SeekBar. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the call stack during the exception:

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C#
0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:122,-1    C#
0x26 in object.1f29ec3d-529a-4f23-9cce-3fd0f5ac1e00 C#
0x2F in System.Reflection.EventInfo.AddEventFrame<Android.Widget.SeekBar, System.EventHandler<Android.Widget.SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs>> at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/EventInfo.cs:222,-1   C#
0x7C in System.Reflection.EventInfo.AddEventHandler at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/EventInfo.cs:110,-1   C#
0xC5 in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.Binding<int,int>.UpdateSourceTrigger at c:\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform (Android)\Helpers\BindingGeneric.cs:342,13    C#
0x172 in MDP_Demo.MainActivity.OnCreate at c:\hgroot\Mobile\MDP Demo\MDP Demo\MainActivity.cs:51,13 C#
0x13 in Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2102,4  C#
0x17 in object.1f29ec3d-529a-4f23-9cce-3fd0f5ac1e00 C#
```

Comment: You should also include the `InvalidCastException` here, as it may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the message I receive. I'm afraid it's not giving me much information other than "Specified cast is not valid". UpdateSourceTrigger returns a Binding<int, int> object.

Comment: I should add that the binding of the TextView works. '_bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(
                () => Vm.TapSelectionText,
                () => TapSelectionLabel.Text));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working, though not the way I would have liked. I had the same exception thrown when I attempted to SetCommand, so I slightly broke MVVM architecture.

```
TapSeekBar.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs>(TapSeekBar_ProgressChanged);
```

...

```
private void TapSeekBar_ProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Vm.TapSelectionProgress = e.Progress;
}
```

Moving the slider now updates the property and triggers UI updates.

Comment: I have added the proper solution below

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for you but I had the same issue a moment ago - digging in the MVVM Light source gave me the hint for the real solution. You need to set the type of the EventArgs for ObserveSourceEvent (the new name for UpdateSourceTrigger), like this:

```
            .ObserveSourceEvent<ProgressChangedEventArgs>(nameof(SeekBar.ProgressChanged)));
```